Compiler not recognizing atomic exchange
I'm creating a kernel for a raspberry pi 3b, and I'm trying to create an atomic class for ints,bools, etc.
I created an Atomic class with loads, stores, etc and they all compile except for my exchange function.
T exchange(T v)
    {
    T old_value;
    __atomic_exchange(&value, &v, &old_value, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST); // compiles when this is     commented out 
    return old_value;
}

aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: build/kernel_cc.o: in function `Atomic<bool>::exchange(bool)':
kernel.cc:(.text._ZN6AtomicIbE8exchangeEb[_ZN6AtomicIbE8exchangeEb]+0x24): undefined reference to `__aarch64_swp1_acq_rel'
make: *** [Makefile:32: kernel8.img] Error 1

This is error I get when trying to compile.
arch64-linux-gnu-g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

This is my compiler version
I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my compiler version or flags or if im calling __atomic_exchange incorrectly
I've tried different compiler flags and do a cmp exchange instead but I get the same error. So I do not really know where to go from here.
If it makes a difference I'm using WSL

I don't know, but there is some discussion here. A quick thing to try is manually add -latomic.

You don't need 'makefile' tag but you need 'c++'.

Your compiler is recognizing it (and compiling it to a call to a helper function), that's why it's a link error rather than a compile-time error.  With optimization enabled, it should inline it unless the object is larger than 8 or maybe 16 bytes.  (Or maybe it only inlines if you let it use ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomics instead of ldax / stlx retry loops, if GCC would rather use the single-instruction atomic via a library than inline the loop if it expects to actually run on a CPU that does support those instructions.)
